# jQuery Selected

Tags: jquery, selected

Im trying to see if a special option in a select-menu has a value equal to 1, and then hide another object. Ive been trying all day but cant figure it out (probably because im a total beginner at jquery)

I have a  select-menu that i populated from a db.
If the option with the id="1" have "selected=selected"
then i want another div to hide when the page is loaded.

This is what i got so far:

```
<select>
<option id="3">test1</option>
<option id="1" selected="selected">test2</option>
<option id="2">test3</option>
</select>
<div id="hide">Hide me</div>


$("#1 option:selected").ready(function () {
   $("#hide").hide();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks..
/Andreas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code I'm afraid:

1. You're using the event on the wrong object - `.ready()` should be applied to the document
2. IDs can't start with a number
3. You should be using the value attribute instead of the id attribute.
4. You're better off using `.val()` to get the value
5. You should give the select an id in case you add another one to the page.

Putting it all together:

```
<select id="foo">
<option value="3">test1</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">test2</option>
<option value="2">test3</option>
</select>
<div id="hide">Hide me</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($('#foo').val() != 1)
       $("#hide").hide();
});
```

If you want to do this dynamically when the select is changed, you can do it like this:

```
$('#foo').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() != 1)
       $("#hide").hide();
   else
       $("#hide").show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.
I am well aware about the points you made about my example. I just quickly wrote down an example of what I tried to do for a simple overview. Point taken, next time I'll be more exact.

I've tried your first example and it works (almost) perfect.
I would like to have the div hide when the selected value is NOT = 1 instead.

Comment: OK I've changed the "==" to "!="

Answer (score 0):

First of all your id is not valid one. It should not start with a number. Provide an id to the select element and find the selected element and check its value to 1 and show/hide the appropriate div.

Answer (score 0):

```
// assume your select has id="mySelect"
$(function() {
    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $('#hide').hide();
        } else {
            $('#hide').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

$('select').change(function(){
  if ($("option:selected",this).attr('id') == 1 ){
   $("#hide").hide();
  }
});

});
```

Will work with what you have, but ditto the points raised by others -

- HTML spec states that you should not have ids starting with numbers
- Use the value attribute for options instead of an id
- You need to put the code in a function that will execute when the change event of the `<select>` is raised
- Give the `<select>` an id to uniquely identify it.